# Saving console output from IIS to file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, console

Because I don't have any Windows Server with IIS on which I can test functionality of the app I want to ask if this code below would work the way I intended - web app writes something to console and I need to save what is written in console to a specific file. I am testing it locally on my laptop with ISS Express installed by Visual Studio 2013.

Is IIS Express the same as IIS on Windows Server so I can use this piece of code below?

```
using (var consoleWriter = new StreamWriter(
            new FileStream(_tempOutputFileName, 
                            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
{
    Console.SetOut(consoleWriter);
    //do some work here with output to console
}


var standardOutput = 
       new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()) { AutoFlush = true };
Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
```

Edit : I can't write to file directly because I need to catch what is written to console by 3rd party library I am using.

Comment: Why don't you write directly to the file?

Comment: I can't since I am using external library and the library writes to console and I need to get what the library writes to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a logging framework, like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and redirect Console output eg. like  [this](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2674).

In log4net you have a lot of appenders , databases etc.

Writing to a file in a IIS enviroment can have security issues.

Comment: Seems I can't use log4net because I am not the one to write to the console but 3rd party app and I couldn't find the way how to log console output from library's methods.